# Modify file embedded in Class Library then Save file

Tags: c#, .net, excel-dna

I've been researching this for a couple weeks and am having a hard time figuring out a solution, I was hoping to gain some insight by posting a somewhat general question here.

I have a Class Library (in this case an .xll) that I have embedded a resource into (a .xlsm).  As you may or may not know, .xlls are associated with Excel so when someone opens the .xll it is loaded into an instance of Excel.  In my scenario when that .xll is loaded into Excel the .xll then loads up a copy of the embedded .xlsm.  So far so good.  This allows me to send out something that, for all intents and purposes, simply appears to be a strange Excel file to my end users at my workplace.

The problem comes in when the user wants to be able to save changes they have made to the Excel Sheet.  If they save it to the desktop (using Excels built in save function) then all that is saved is the .xlsm.  When that .xlsm is opened again the .xll is no longer loaded and any .NET features included in the .xlsm will not function.

A couple questions probably arise at this point.  Firstly, why not just register the .xll with the system?  Mainly because if I registered the .xll then every time someone opens up Excel that .xll would open, which means my embedded .xlsm would open too (remember, that's what the .xll does on start up.)  Users tend to find that annoying... :-).

Nextly, why not just send both files?  Answer: Too much disruption for the end user (just bear with me on this).  Love it or hate it, they want one file to open and then modify.  To them an .xll is just another version of an .xlsm, and I would prefer they retained that perception as it makes explaining myself much easier.

Lastly, why not just distribute the .xll to my group as a whole and release .xlsms against that?  Answer: These .xlls will get sent to a whole bunch of random places where I can't control what the user will have on their machine, so I prefer to keep things self contained.

There are two basic solutions that come to mind.

**Option one** is to figure out how to simply recompile the .xll on the fly from the .xlsm (probably via an instance of the .xll), and then save that .xll to a place of the users choosing.  This would require me to create my own save method since Excel won't help with that and probably include me needing to intercept any effort the user makes at saving so I can redirect them to my own save method.  The problem is I can't figure out how to make the .xll recompile itself, especially since I'll be sending the .xll out to machines that don't necessarily have an SDK on them.  And on top of that, forcing a user to use my own save method would be another unwelcome disruption (at least in my opinion...)

**Option two** Is to create an assembly that works as an executable.  Basically it would contain the .xlsm as well as the .xll and the executable would load up Excel and then apply the .xll to it.  So long as the executable doesn't need admin privileges, I think I'll be fine sending them out in place of regular old file (most people around here never even see the extension anyway, with the right icon, most people can't tell the difference).  The only problem is I can't figure out how to link an .xlsm to a assembly without using a resource file and turning the .xlsm into bytecode.  Which basically puts us back at square one.

**In essence**, option 1 requires me to figure out how to compile on a foreign machine and option 2 requires me to figure how to contain a whole .xlsm so that I can modify it and place it back where it was...or at least putting it somewhere the executable can find it again easily.

Anyway, if you made it this far you have my eternal gratitude.  I'm just stuck trying to figure out where to look next and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.